# Anaconda Navigator からコマンドプロンプトや Jupyter Notebook を起動できない

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Anaconda Navigatorを起動したあと、”Launch”ボタンを押しても”CMD.exe Prompt”や”Jupyter Notebook”を開けなくなり困っております。

元々は正常に動作していましたが、TensorFlowでGPUを使えるようにするために試行錯誤していたところ、上記の状態になりました。その過程で、CUDAやVisual studioのインストール、環境変数の操作、などを行っております。

スタートメニューからは、”Anaconda Prompt”と”Jupyter Notebook”のどちらも開けます。アンインストールと再インストールを行いましたが、状態は変わりませんでした。

Navigatorそのものが起動しないという質問はみかけるのですが、Navigatorを起動できる状態でLaunchできないケースについて原因や解決方法をご存じの方はおられますでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: アンインストールが不完全か、加えてAnacondaのAll UsersとJust Meを変えてインストールした可能性とかが考えられます。[Windows10でAnacondaをアンインストールする方法](https://senriblog.com/windows10-anaconda-uninstall/), [python : condaを使用してJupyter-Labを完全にアンインストールします](https://www.fixes.pub/program/205731.html), [M.S.WindowsにPython3 (Anaconda3) を導入する（7つの罠）](https://qiita.com/kaizen_nagoya/items/7bfd7ecdc4e8edcbd679), [\[Python\]Anacondaをアンインストールしてから「All Users」設定で再インストールしてみた](https://note.com/hotta3216/n/n9a12faf675f9) 他にスタートメニューのショートカットや C:/Users/usename直下の`.`で始まるディレクトリで、関連するものも削除するかリネームで退避しておいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: @kunif さん　参考になるリンクをありがとうございます。操作した箇所を遡りつつ、隠れているディレクトリの残留ファイルなどを掃除して、きれいにアンインストールしてから再インストールしたところ正常な動作に戻りました。

Comment: 具体的に何が消し切れていなかったか/再インストールでは更新されていなかったかとかを、出来れば自己回答にしてみてください。